# Push segue in iOS 5 not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, push, segue

I am very much new to IOS. I am using the storyboard feature to create a app

Here is what I want. I have two view Controllers, say oneViewController and twoViewController

I have a button on oneViewController. I ctrl+dragged the button from oneViewController to twoViewController and selected push from Segue.

I compiled the app on iOS 5.0 and run it, and it's not working. I changed push to model and it worked. Am I missing anything?

I am using the a part of [this link](http://kurrytran.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html) and [this link](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219) as a guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "push" `segue` is modeled for use with changing views from the `UITableViewController (UINavigationController)`, modal is acceptable switching between `UIViewControllers`.

Modal transitions...

[image]

Comment: Ok.. But the view is appearing from the bottom instead of sliding in from right/left

Comment: Right, if you want the left/right functionality you'll have to use a UINavigationController. However sense you are using UIViewControllers, you have to switch between them modally. I have updated my answer to show the list of transition effects for a modal segue.

Comment: what about custom segue.. do you hav any example on how to use that

Comment: In the tutorials you linked, the author was able to use the Push segue because he was setting up UINavigationControllers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9596408/716216 this will show you how to create a custom segue, but I don't know how much luck you'll have designing a push segue as custom for a view change that is meant to be modal... probably just a lot of crashing. Good luck though!