# Storyboard: inferring navigation bar after changing segues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, storyboard, segue

I am developing a navigation-based app with few views. In the Storyboard, I have a `Navigation Controller` that points to my main ViewController ("center" view of my app) that points to other views with segues.

At first I wanted this segues to be `push` but it didn't work properly (the buttons were hardly responding), I've switched to `modal` ([as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837780/963881)). Now the segue works fine but whenever I use `modal` segue, the navigation bar in view it points to disappears (I've tried with other configurations - the navbar is being shown on Storyboard but doesn't work on Simulator).

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by JoePasq, "Have your view controller class the root view controller of the navigation controller". Select your view controller which you want to set as Root screen and goto Editor/EmbedIn option and select navigation controller. You will get a  navigation-controller embedded with your root view controller. Instead of setting up segues you can change your screens programmatically in your program. In your method for button click event write a similar code as below;

```
- (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender {
UIStoryBoard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; //MainStoryboard is the name of your storyboard
SecondViewController *secondView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sView"];
//sView is the identifier name set by the user, (present inside Attribute Inspector - View Controller)
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

Let me know if this works or there is also another way to do it.

Comment: The solution you've provided is OK, but I still don't understand why can't I do this with Storyboard (and why I have do it programatically instead). Now the only reason for me to add another 2 files with for this with ViewController for this View will be IBAction segues.

Comment: I think u have to embed a navigationController to your View for navigating from one screen to the other.

Answer (score 2):

With a modal presentation your view controller is no longer part of the `UINavigation` stack. You can drag in a new `UINavigationController`, display that as a modal view and have your view controller class the root view controller of the navigation controller.