# Connecting three views to a single navigation controller (XCode 7, Swift 2)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7

I am unsure of how to link three Views (1 table view, one view that adds data to the table view through core data and one camera view) to the one view controller each with individual buttons.

I've tried to search to find a tutorial for linking views through the storyboard but have found none that help.

If I could have some instructions on to how I can do this (through code or storyboard) that would be much appreciated.

Comment: So if I understood it right, you wanna connect three buttons in your storyboard to open different views in storyboard. If yes, you can use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595280/xcode-4-uibutton-segue-push-to-table-view-controller

Comment: The accepted answer in post @manman's comment shows how to create custom segues. Just using the push or modal segue should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood it right, you wanna connect three buttons in your storyboard to open different views in storyboard. If yes, you can use this approach: [Xcode 4 UIButton segue push to Table View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595280/xcode-4-uibutton-segue-push-to-table-view-controller)